# Overlapping images selection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I have a set of overlapping images covering some area, and my goal is to build a union image, whereas each pixel of the final image corresponds to an appropriate pixel of one of the source images. So, the goal is to select an appropriate source image for every pixel.

Formally speaking we have the following:

- Every pixel of each source image has its score.
- If two adjacent pixels of the final image are from different source images - there's a penalty, which depends on the specific pixel and the source images.

The goal is to maximize the overall score.

Simply speaking the goal is to build a *mosaic* of images, whereas the image quality is not uniform within an image, plus the mosaic cut lines should be where they are least visible.

It's a real-world problem, hence the pixel score is a smooth slowly-varying function, and the "pixel" selection should not be treated literally, it's more about selecting appropriate *regions*.

My current algorithm is as following:

1. Select the source image from the highest-scoring source image
2. Unite adjacent pixels from the same source into clouds.
3. Local optimization of cloud border wrt the penalty.
4. Test for clouds that can vanish completely (i.e. the score gain from its interior doesn't justify the penalty of its border)

Is this a known problem with (hopefully) known solutions? Approximate solution should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a well-known problem in Computer Graphics research.

It is typically approached as a discrete optimization problem where each pixel in the overlap area is a discrete variable, with one state for each possible source of the pixel. The energy (or error) function to be minimized typically contains terms penalizing transitions in areas where the human eye is likely to detect them (e.g. it penalizes cutting off strong gradients), and terms that encourage neighboring pixels to be selected from the same source.

Once the energy function is defined, it is often solved with an algorithm called Graphcuts. This algorithm is related to the max flow / min cut problem in graphs, but it can be used to solve a fairly large class of discrete optimization problems. Note that implementing Graph Cuts is non-trivial, and you should probably look for code. `boost::graph` has an implementation of the Boykow-Kolmogorov algorithm, afaik, which is the max flow / min cut algorithm variant typically used for Graphcut problems on grids (i.e. images).

To get you started, look at the following paper:

http://www.cc.gatech.edu/cpl/projects/graphcuttextures/gc-final-lowres.pdf

It is about stitching images together to create textures (and also about stitching videos), but in essence it does something very similar to what you want to achieve.

Also, google for "image stitching" or "image mosaic", probably in conjunction with "SIGGRAPH", which is the main scientific conference in graphics.

Answer (score -1):

SIFT and SURF methods are state of the art in literature for solving this problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF

Comment: I think the question is not about aligning the image but about stitching them together. This is not what SIFT and SURF are used for.